# Resolve symlinks with boost filesystem

Tags: c++, linux, boost, filesystems

I expect there is a simple way of doing this but I haven't been able to uncover this even with some intense googling.

How can I use boost::filesystem to find the location a symlink ( on *nix systems ) points to?

Answer (score 14):

If you are using v3 of `boost::filesystem` you can use the [canonical](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical) function to get a path with all symlinks resolved.  This may work for resolving the path of your symlink.

For example, if sym.link is a symlink:

```
boost::filesystem::path resolved = boost::filesystem::canonical( 'sym.link' );
```

I've not actually tried this so I could be wrong, but seems to make sense.

Alternatively, you might have some luck with [read_symlink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#read_symlink)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`read_symlink()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#read_symlink) function of Version 3:

> ```
> path read_symlink(const path& p);
> path read_symlink(const path& p, system::error_code& ec);
> ```
>
> *Returns*:  If `p` resolves to a symbolic link, a path object containing the contents of that symbolic link. Otherwise an empty path object.
>
> *Throws*: As specified in Error reporting. [Note: It is an error if p does not resolve to a symbolic link. -- end note]