# C++ equivalent of 'readlink -f'

Tags: c++, readlink

In `unistd.h`, I have the C function `readlink`, which follows a link down one target. The coreutil `readlink` has the great `-f` option to follow every sym link recursively. How can I get this behavior in C++? A boost library, a posix function I don't know about, etc?

** Edit ** was just looking at the man page for `realpath`. Is this giving the same 'canonical' expansion of `readlink -f`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417976/resolve-symlinks-with-boost-filesystem

Comment: You could try stracing readlink -f and then see what it does there

Comment: @PlasmaHH: You could also look at the source; `readlink` is part of GNU Coreutils. I suspect it just repeatedly invokes the `readlink` system call; it would be easy enough to do the same in your own program.

Comment: @Vadim looking at the documentation of boost canonical function, it sounds like it does the same thing as realpath, i.e. get an absolute path without symlinks and  '.', '..' and double '/'. That sounds pretty close to what I want.

Comment: There's a `readlink()` function in the POSIX C library. Apply it in a loop until it finds a file that is not a symlink. Done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `realpath` is the equivalent of `readlink -f`.

See [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do exactly this today and the suggestion to use realpath() failed because the symlink was relative! If you are using glibc, consider canonicalize_file_name (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/canonicalize_file_name.3.html).

Of course, I found that after I wrote this code. I don't know how cross-platform this is. I wouldn't recommend it if canonicalize_file_name is available for you, but it might be a good starting point :)

```
char *readlink_f(const char *path) {
    struct stat sb;
    char *linkname = NULL;
    ssize_t r;
    int ret = -1;
    char *ptmp = NULL;
    char *dir; // not allocated
    char *relpath = NULL;
    char *abspath = NULL;

    /* create enough space to read the link into */
    if (lstat(path, &sb) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to lstat the path\n");
        goto error;
    }
    linkname = malloc(sb.st_size + 1);
    if (linkname == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "insufficient memory\n");
        goto error;
    }
    r = readlink(path, linkname, sb.st_size + 1);
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to readlink the path\n");
        goto error;
    }
    if (r > sb.st_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "symlink increased in size between lstat() and readlink()\n");
        goto error;
    }
    linkname[sb.st_size] = '\0';

    if (linkname[0] != '/') {
        /* realpath fails with relative symlinks */
        ptmp = strdup(path); /* dirname modifies its argument */
        dir = dirname(ptmp);
        if (asprintf(&relpath, "%s/%s", dir, linkname) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get generate absolute path\n");
            goto error;
        }
    } else {
        relpath = strdup(linkname);
    }

    /* canonicalize the path */
    abspath = realpath(relpath, NULL);
    if (!abspath) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to get canonical path\n");
        goto error;
    }

    goto cleanup;

error:
    free(abspath);
    abspath = NULL;

cleanup:
    free(linkname);
    free(ptmp);
    free(relpath);
    return abspath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you can use [`std::filesystem::canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) (or `weakly_canonical` if the file doesn't have to exist). It is also cross-platform. If you can't use C++17 yet, you may still be able to use the [`std::filesystem::experimental`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/canonical) version.